# How to change this function to the recursive function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I have the following code that compares the `node.Text`o each both given node sets and then return one if they are equal otherwise zero. But my problem is that it just compare the first children because of `nodes2.Nodes[ii]` hence I know that it will not go forward more.

As I know if it was `TreeNodeCollection` it was easy to do recursive for each node and sub-node using `foreach` loop.

But here how I could change the code to the recursive version? 
thanks in advance!

```
public int Compare_ChildNodes(TreeNode nodes1, TreeNode nodes2)
{
    int length_children1 = nodes1.Nodes.Count;
    int length_children2 = nodes2.Nodes.Count;
    int result_int = 1;
    if (length_children1 != length_children2)
    {
        result_int = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < length_children1; ii++)
        {
            if (nodes1.Nodes[ii].Text.Equals(nodes2.Nodes[ii].Text))
            {
                int ret = Compare_ChildNodes(nodes1.Nodes[ii], nodes2.Nodes[ii]);
                result_int = ret;
            }
            else
            {
                result_int = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return result_int;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any problems here. Calling `Compare_ChildNodes` with `nodes1.Nodes[ii]` and `nodes2.Nodes[ii]` does exactly the recursion you want.

I'd just suggest a little optimization ("early out") for your code:

```
public int Compare_ChildNodes(TreeNode nodes1, TreeNode nodes2)
{
    int length_children1 = nodes1.Nodes.Count;
    int length_children2 = nodes2.Nodes.Count;
    int result_int = 1;

    if (!nodes1.Text.Equals(nodes2.Text)) return 0; // not equal
    if (length_children1 != length_children2) return 0; // not equal

    return nodes1.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>.Select((node, idx) => 
         Compare_ChildNodes(node, nodes2.Nodes[idx]).Any(result => result == 0) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

I changed the comparison for the node's text to another recursion level so you can recurse using linq.

The linq `Any` method checks if any of the comparisons (in the [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method) returns `0` indicating that a child node collection is not equal.

The [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is called for each `TreeNode` in `node1.Nodes` and with it's index in that collection. So you can use this index to get the matching node from `node2.Nodes` and call `Compare_ChildNodes` for these two.

As soon as you find unequal (child-)nodes, you can return `0` and don't need to continue comparing the other nodes.

If you cannot use the linq statements (for Framework reasons or others), you can still use your `for` loop:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < length_children1; idx++)
    if (Compare_ChildNodes(nodes1.Nodes[idx], nodes2.Nodes[idx]) == 0)
        return 0;
return 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! but I have this error: `Error 1 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.OfType<TResult>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh this should actually be `System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<TResult>`. Can you check your `using` statements?

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh added a non-linq version to my answer.

Comment: I have these `using` statements: `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: @SaberJalilzadeh This is an interesting problem...I don't know why your compiler does not choose `Enumerable.OfType`...works fine here. Your `TreeNode`s are `System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode`?

Comment: Yes I have as `TreeNodes are System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode`.

Comment: Can't solve this now (have to work a little). Please refer to my non-linq solution. And I would be interested if you open a new question about why your compiler chooses the wrong extension.